# How to fix my Password parameter using PDO

Tags: php, mysqli

i have a query using PDO. password match was successful when I enter only strings or number. But when my password contains @& or anything like that it will tell that password is incorrect. Though in my database that was the right password.

```
session_start();
// Change this to your connection info.
$DATABASE_HOST = 'localhost';
$DATABASE_USER = 'root';
$DATABASE_PASS = '';
$DATABASE_NAME = 'Data-Six';
// Try and connect using the info above.
$con = mysqli_connect($DATABASE_HOST, $DATABASE_USER, $DATABASE_PASS, $DATABASE_NAME);
if ( mysqli_connect_errno() ) {
    // If there is an error with the connection, stop the script and display the error.
    die ('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Now we check if the data from the login form was submitted, isset() will check if the data exists.
if ( !isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']) ) {
    // Could not get the data that should have been sent.
    die ('Please fill both the username and password field!');
}

// Prepare our SQL, preparing the SQL statement will prevent SQL injection.
if ($stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT `used-id`, `username`, `password` FROM `user-list` WHERE `username` = ?')) {
    // Bind parameters (s = string, i = int, b = blob, etc), in our case the username is a string so we use "s"
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
    $stmt->execute();
    // Store the result so we can check if the account exists in the database.
    $stmt->store_result();

}

if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
    $stmt->bind_result($username, $password, $id);
    $stmt->fetch();
    // Account exists, now we verify the password.
    // Note: remember to use password_hash in your registration file to store the hashed passwords.
    if ($_POST['password'] === $password) {
        // Verification success! User has loggedin!
        // Create sessions so we know the user is logged in, they basically act like cookies but remember the data on the server.
        session_regenerate_id();
        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
        $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['username'];
        $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
        echo 'Welcome ' . $_SESSION['name'] . '!';
    } else {
        echo 'Incorrect password!';
    }
} else {
    echo 'Incorrect username!';
}
$stmt->close();
?>
```

Comment: `var_dump($password);` and `var_dump($_POST['password']);`. What do you see?

Comment: @FrankerZ where do i include that?

Comment: Where you're checking the password...

Comment: `SELECT \`used-id\`, \`username\`, \`password\`...` -> `$stmt->bind_result($username, $password, $id);` - looks like you'd be comparing `$_POST['password']` with the username returned from the database as you're binding `used-id` -> `$username`, `username` -> `$password` and `password` -> $id.

Comment: It seems like you store the passwords in plaintext. I seriously hope that you will change that behaviour sooner than later.

Comment: for example: My password is 'con@' but then when i put the var_dump, it says string(3)con (it didn't catch the "@")

Comment: it mean you strip down any special characters when WRITING the password into the database

Comment: @CD001 thanks to you. i got the answer dude.

Answer (score 3):

The order of variables in bind_result doesn't follow the order of field names in the SQL query.

That said, store_result/bind_result is outdated and inconvenient method which was replaced by get_result that gets you a conventional PHP array.

Here is the code you need:

```
$sql = 'SELECT `used-id`, `username`, `password` FROM `user-list` WHERE `username` = ?';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST['username']);
$stmt->execute();
$user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();

// if ($_POST['password'] === $password) { come onm you MUST use a hash
if ($user && password_verify($_POST['password'], $user['password']))
{
    ...
}
```

as you can see it is much more concise and convenient

Answer (score -5):

I just figured out how to used the PDO statement XD! thanks team. what i did was just rearranged the query to match the Bind-result.

```
 if ($stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT `username`, `password`, `used-id` FROM `user-list` WHERE `username` = ?')) {

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->store_result();  
}
if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
$stmt->bind_result($username, $password, $id);
$stmt->fetch();


if ($_POST['password'] === $password) {


    session_regenerate_id();
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
    $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['username'];
    $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
    echo 'Welcome ' . $_SESSION['name'] . '!';
    echo 'Welcome ' . $_SESSION['id'] . '!';
} else {
    echo 'Incorrect password!';
}
} else {
echo 'Incorrect username!';
}
```

Comment: NO! Don't store cleartext passwords anywhere. Use `password_verify()` and secure your passwords as Your Common Sense showed above.

Comment: @FrankerZ yeah. i kinda use cleartext. i only code for the Login Process dude. my password from database was manually encoded. My next thing to do is to create a registration form with MD5 hash password. then ill use that `password_verify`

Comment: Forget about MD5. It should not be for passwords.